# Mongo's updateMany with rename doesn't update for some fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Desctiption**

MongoDB's `updateMany` method doesn't update any documents when used with `$rename` on some fields.

**Example**

I try to rename the fields `blog.blog_ttile` and `blog.blog_cotnet`. I checked for typos, there are none.

```
Example model:

User: {
  name,
  email,
  blog: {
    blog_ttile,
    blog_cotnet
  }
}
```

Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('User');

const nameChanges = {
  "blog.blog_ttile": 'blog.title',
  'blog.blog_cotnet': 'blog.content',
};

async function performNameChanges() {
  try {
    const updatedDocuments = await User.updateMany({}, { $rename: nameChanges }); 

    console.log({ updatedDocuments });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{ updatedDocuments: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } }
```

**Additional details**

Some fields are correctly recognized. Let's say `email` in the above example. However, when I try to update the updated name, it doesn't work again. Interestingly, it still detects the original name.

*Example*:

Renaming `email` to `personal_email` works. Renaming `personal_email` to `email` afterwards doesn't and returns `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`. Calling a rename on `email` a second time returns `{ n: <total_records>, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` although no documents have `email` anymore`.

What could be causing this?

**Note:**
This question applies for MongoDB without Mongoose with `db.getCollection("User").updateMany` instead of `User.updateMany`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried doing the same in MongoDB. It works as expected. In your case I'm suspecting Mongoose schema to be the cause of this weird behavior. Mongoose Schema has to have the field you are looking to rename. If the field doesn't exist, it returns nModified 0. The schema will need to have both the old and the new names. Old ones to allow the migration, and the new ones for the new logic in the code.

Your return result is:

```
{ updatedDocuments: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } }
```

How is this possible? n=0? for query {}. It is only possible when there are no elements in your collection. n means matched count, it must be equal to total number of records in your collection.

> Renaming email to personal_email works

Before first update your schema is fine. But after rename (first update), you should update your schema to :

```
User: {
  name,
  personal_email,
  blog: {
    blog_tile,
    blog_contnet
  }
}
```

before running the second update (renaming back to email).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was the Schema. I updated the schema to the new fields before running the rename method. Having both the old and new names in the schema makes this work.

Comment: I made an edit to describe why the Schema may be causing this. It's not accepted yet. I'll mark your answer accepted as soon as the details about the actual cause is in there.

Comment: I had stuck to the same problem too, I've just inserted the old key configuration into the Schema and ran the code, then it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use like this thanks you

```
import { connect } from '../database';

export const renameFileds = async () => {
  const db = connect();
  //let userlist = await db.UserModel.find();
  const updatedDocuments = await db.UserModel.updateMany(
    {},
    { $rename: { image: 'picture' } },
    {
      // Strict allows to update keys that do not exist anymore in the schema
      strict: false,
    }
  ).exec();

  console.log({ updatedDocuments });
};
renameFileds();
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other answer, it's because your mongoose schema didn't contain the field you wanted to rename.

Instead of keeping the old field around while the migration occurs, you can also specify `strict: false` in the options, and mongoose will not discard unknown paths:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('User');

const nameChanges = {
  "blog.blog_ttile": 'blog.title',
  'blog.blog_cotnet': 'blog.content',
};

async function performNameChanges() {
  try {
    const updatedDocuments = await User.updateMany(
      {},
      { $rename: nameChanges },
      {
        // Strict allows to update keys that do not exist anymore in the schema
        strict: false,
      }
    ).exec();

    console.log({ updatedDocuments });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```